# How to create a questions from past modal verb sentences

Tags: grammar, word-order, modal-verbs

I have no idea why my question was closed as it was pretty clear (at least for a person of average intelligence) so I am trying again:
There is a sentence, e.g:

> He could have seen that.

Will the question be:

> Could he have seen that?

And with how, will it be like this?

> How could he have seen that?

Comment: Nice ad hominem right there. Now compare this question with your [previous one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72985/question-with-past-modal-verb), *how much better worded and more to the point* this one is and *what mistakes (or typos) you've fixed all by yourself*. You should have done that to the original question, though, rather than posting a new one.

Comment: Sorry, it was not meant to moderators, I just think it was clear and simple enough for everyone.

Comment: Of course you as the question asker would think that. That's why you asked it like that in the first place. But only others can tell you for sure if it's really clear and simple enough for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the questions would be as you have shown them.